# Should I write {from that torment called "prison"} or {from the prison of torment}?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was reading an article where I saw Frank, John and Anglin three friends were released from a prison after 3 years. They were tortured brutally everyday while in prison. After reading that article I was thinking if I could also get rid of my bad luck like they were freed from that painful life! Because, I was comparing my misfortune or bad luck with a prison and I want to get rid of it. So, if I summarize the whole thing, can I say these sentences :

> 1. At last Frank, John and Anglin are released **from that torment called "prison"**, but will I ever be released from this prison called "bad luck"!
> 2. At last Frank, John and Anglin are released **from the prison of torment**, but will I ever be freed from this prison of bad luck !

NB : *Actually I want to make a sentence that fit the context. I would be grateful if you could correct my mistakes and also tell me the natural way of saying those sentences.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those sentences both sound natural and they are both grammatically correct except for the exclamation point at the end. You want a question mark because you are asking a question:

> 1. ...will I ever be released from this prison called "bad luck"?
> 2. ...will I ever be freed from this prison of bad luck?

I don't know what you mean by "fit the context." I like those sentences very much; they are very expressive and articulate your personal desires very clearly. You feel imprisoned by bad luck the same way those three friends were imprisoned. They were released and you wonder if ever you will be released like they were. I have seen many people draw similar analogies between stories in the news or in novels and their own life situations. From that perspective, I think your sentences fit the context very well.

Maybe I'm missing something. That's the best I can do with the information I've got.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sarah.